# Problem in updating rails from 4.2.0 to 5.0.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```rb
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    active_model_serializers (~> 0.10.0.rc5) was resolved to 0.10.9, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 4.1, < 6)

    axlsx_rails (~> 0.5.0) was resolved to 0.5.2, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 3.1)

    haml-rails was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 4.0.1)

    rails (= 5.0.2) was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
      actionpack (= 5.0.2)

    responders (~> 2.0) was resolved to 2.4.1, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 4.2.0, < 6.0)

    rspec-rails (~> 3.0) was resolved to 3.8.2, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 3.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    activerecord-postgis-adapter (~> 3.1.4) was resolved to 3.1.5, which depends on
      activerecord (~> 4.2)

    rails (= 5.0.2) was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
      activerecord (= 5.0.2)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 5.0.2)

    leaflet-rails was resolved to 1.5.1, which depends on
      rails (>= 4.2.0)

    react-rails (~> 1.6.0) was resolved to 1.6.2, which depends on
      rails (>= 3.2)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "resque":
  In Gemfile:
    resque (~> 1.26.0)

    resque-scheduler (~> 4.3.0) was resolved to 4.3.1, which depends on
      resque (~> 1.26)
```

I changed the file "GemFile" to 5.0.2 and gave an error. The error does not say that any gem does not support 5.0.2. Help me please.
Reason for update due to:

```rb
dayanov-sa@dayanov-sa:~/workspace/main/sokol_dev$ rails c
/home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/duplicable.rb:85: warning: BigDecimal.new is deprecated; use BigDecimal() method instead.
/home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
Traceback (most recent call last):
        7948: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
        7947: from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        7946: from /home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        7945: from /home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        7944: from /home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:67:in `console'
        7943: from /home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:142:in `require_application_and_environment!'
        7942: from /home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
        7941: from /home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
         ... 7936 levels...
           4: from /home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
           3: from /home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
           2: from /home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
           1: from /home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
/home/dayanov-sa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

I tried many methods to solve this problem, but nothing helped. Has anyone encountered a similar situation and knows some way to solve this problem.

Rails 4.2.0

ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: post your Gemfile

Comment: @NickM https://dropmefiles.com/QWhkZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, the ol' Rails major version bump task.

Looks like many of your gems are set up with specific versions in your Gemfile. Changing the rails gem version alone will not do, you will get a lot of dependency errors and what's worse, that's just the start - lots of other things can go bad later.

You can remove versions from all gems and then set rails to 5.2 or whatever, then work your way through dependency errors as they pop up. Expect this to be a lengthy process and obviously don't do it on the production machine.

You may even need or find it more convenient in certain cases to apply updates to underlying services such as databases.

If you don't have any specs/tests you will want to test the entire application, or start writing them.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html

Comment: Can I install a second ruby on rails besides the main one?

Comment: You can but that doesn’t mean you should. I’d keep it separate, fire up some $5 VM and work there, sometimes it’s best keeping things separate to avoid any problems which may translate into time waste.

Answer (score 1):

did you run `bundle install` after changing in Gemfile? and its not recommended to upgrade to Rails 5.2 directly.. first make it stable and running in rails 5.0 and then in 5.1